# Casimir Force between two circular conducting plates

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, casimir-effect

I'd be happy if someone could tell me where to find a derivation (if there is even one) or if there exists an explicit expression that estimates the [Casimir force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) between two parallel **circular** conducting plates because I found none.

EDIT: two parallel CIRCULAR conducting plates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These short notes,](http://physweb.bgu.ac.il/COURSES/QuantumMechCohen/Contributions/Casimir_Effect.pdf) by Asaf Szulc of BGU, are really nice.  He gives a modern derivation and an "old school one."  Then straight to the application to parallel conducting plates.  Level is pitched at intro grad student, but you can read diagonally (lots of conceptual explanations) or go straight to the motivation and parallel plate.   In particular, he derives the force per unit area (assuming a generic permittivity between.  This can be adapted to give the total force depending on the shape of the plates.

Comment: Hello. I edited my posts. I meant to type circular conducting plates.

Comment: If the circles are aligned as with the plates it's essentially the same.  You get pressure.  Integrate to get discs.  Unless you're interested in the edge effects.

Comment: I meant you get the force between plates.

Comment: I was kind of trying to derive this following what my textbook did for the case of a parallelepiped (Introductory Quantum Optics, page 32, http://qiqo.hznu.edu.cn/upLoad/down/month_1406/201406231000574799.pdf) but I'm stuck and not sure how to apply it. However, can I generally assume that the  known expression for the Casimir force can be applied for any shape of the plates considering the same configuration as the original? If so,  is it because the boundary conditions don't change in the limit where the separation between the plates is much smaller than their size?

Comment: there are two dice derivations in the link.  for me, if I can't understand a derivation I'll try to find another one or two.  Maybe I can understand them.  Then I go back to the original confusing one and it's usually obvious what tripped me up.  For the second question, the result given is force/area, not force.  So if your question is to calculate the total force, just integrate this over the disc.  If it's just the F/A, then it's the same since, as you observe, the distance between plates is much much less than their extent.

Comment: I understand the way the answer was derived and that the result is force/area, but if I want the total force I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "integrate this over the disc". Does "this" refer to the original known case for force/area (prop. to 1/d^4) and you're telling me to integrate it over a circle? If so, that practically means just multiplying the result of force/area by area. I apologize if I'm over-complicating things but this doesn't seem right for some reason.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Since pressure is a constant except near the edge.

Comment: I see. I'll try looking into this a little more. Thank you for all the help John!